# How to export my figure so that its scaling matches the original

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have to recreate Extended figure 4b from this paper https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-023-06594-4/figures/8.

I have finished coding for my figure, but I'm struggling to get its scaling right, this is the code I used to export it.

`ggsave(file="~/Desktop/plot.svg", plot=grouped_bar_chart, width=6.1, height=3.7,units = "cm",dpi = 300)`.

I chose the height and the width based off me printing the PDF and physcially measuring it, then applying the dimensions to my figure. However, when I open the `svg` its a lot smaller than the original.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't just look smaller in the software you're opening it in? When I export a plot with your setting from above, the first line of the SVG file (where the dimensions are defined) says "width='172.91pt' height='104.88pt'". Plonking that into Wolfram alpha and asking it to convert points to cm yields exactly 6.1 and 3.7 for width and height respectively.

Comment: I realised that my figure is smaller after exporting it, it comes out with the dimensions 5.9 cm and 3.5 cm. Could it be because I am using a Macbook?

Comment: Eh, difficult to say. The concept of a fixed size does not translate well into the world of vector graphics. Try opening the SVG in a text editor. Do the numbers in the first line differ from those I posted above? If yes it's an R problem, if no it's problem with the software that gave you the 5.9 cm.